# Keras multi classifier is always giving 0 output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I built this keras model for multi classification

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

This is my data, normalized

[image: Normalized Data]

And these are my target values from 0 to 5

[image: Target values]

I used this code to prepare dataset

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dff[:92000], target[:92000]))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dff[500:520]))
# random slice of test dataset

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(100)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1)
```

Then I trained and tested my model using this

```
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20) 

predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)
classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis = 1)
```

classes output is always 0: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

I already tried without normalizing my data, but output was still same.

Comment: As you say multi-class and set such loss function, then what is this about  `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`?

Comment: You should probably change it to `Dense(5, activation='softmax')`

Comment: Furthermore, your last dense layer has only *1* unit which means your outputs has a size `(1,)` and you are applying argmax operation that results getting index 0 everytime.

Comment: @Jatin, Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: @M.Innat apologies for such a long delay. Thanks a lot it worked fine! I got so busy solving other errors that I completely forgot about this thread.

Comment: @Frightera Thanks a lot, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

> After changing it to `Dense(5, activation='softmax')` has resolved the issue (paraphrased from M.Innat)

Working code as shown below

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

> Keras multi classifier is always giving 0 output is due to your last > dense layer has only 1 unit which means your outputs has a
> size (1,) and you are applying argmax operation that results getting
> index 0 everytime (paraphrased from Frightera)